# multiplying a vector (1 x N) by a tensor (N x M x M)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I am looking for a matrix operation in numpy or preferably in pytorch that allows one to multiply a vector (1 x N) by a tensor (N x M x M) and get (1 x M x M).  This is easily accomplished using a for loop, but the for loop does not allow back propagation during training. I tried using matmul in numpy and pytorch (and several others such as dot and bmm), but could not get any to work. Here is an example (where M=2, but is 256 in my use case) of what I am trying to do:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]])
```

I would like to perform the operation: `1*[[1,2],[3,4]] + 2*[[5,6],[7,8]] + 3*[[9,10],[11,12]]`, which can be achieved with a for loop like this:

```
for i in range(3):
  matrix_sum += a[i]*b[i]
```

Any advice or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `A@B` rule is that the last dim of A pairs with the 2nd to the last of B.  `N` is this dimension, so `B` needs to be changed to (M,N,M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy and pytorch were built uppon matrix multiplications!

Torch example:

```
A = torch.rand(1, N)
B = torch.rand(N, M, M)

C = A @ B.transpose(0, 1) 
C.transpose_(0, 1)
C.shape
torch.size(1, M, M)
```

And similarly for numpy:

```
A = np.random.randn(1, N)
B = np.random.randn(N, M, M)

C = A @ B.transpose(1, 0, 2)
C = C.transpose(1, 0, 2)
C.shape
(1, M, M)
```

**Edit** For the Einsum lovers:

Pytorch and numpy handle einsum pretty much in the same way:

```
torch.einsum('i,ijk->jk', A, B)
np.einsum('i,ijk->jk', A, B)
```

Pytorch einsum documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.einsum.html
Numpy einsum documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

Comment: I edited your typo but you reversed it :D shouldn't it be `transpose` instead of `transopose`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple einsum:

```
#this gives you 2-D array (M,M)
np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',a,b)
```

output:

```
[[38 44]
 [50 56]]
```

or another solution:

```
#this gives you 3-D array (1,M,M)
a[None,:]@b.swapaxes(0,1)
```

output:

```
[[[38 44]
  [50 56]]]
```